# Cast IList to IEnumerable

Tags: c#

Code snip 1) does not compile, and I need e.g. to make the cast as in snip 2)
if I for some reason want test declared as it is. But why can't the compiler make that cast, this is e.g. the cast for snip 3)

1)

```
static IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>> DoStuff()
{
  var test = new Dictionary<int, IList<int>>() { { 1, new List<int>() { 1, 2 } } };
  return test;
}
```

2)

```
static IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>> DoStuff()
{
  var test = new Dictionary<int, IList<int>>() { { 1, new List<int>() { 1, 2 } } };
  return test.ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => (IEnumerable<int>)item.Value);
}
```

3)

```
static IEnumerable<int> DoStuff()
{
  var test = new List<int>() { 1, 2 };
  return test;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Variance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx) is supported in .NET 4, but in your case, netiher IDictionary<> nor IList<> are variant types, hence can't be automatically converted to another IDictionary<>.

Answer (score 2):

It is because `IDictionary<int, IList<int>>` does not inherit/implement `IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>>`

Your first example can be changed to this and should work:

```
static IDictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>> DoStuff()
{
  var test = new Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<int>>() { { 1, new List<int>() { 1, 2 } } };
  return test;
}
```